# Have to create a temp table to view in a procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, cursor, temp-tables

Procedure summary: I have created a cursor and extracted data and inserted in a table mm_dummy_table which i created in my db.
I do not want the data to be stored in a created table,a temporary table should be created for that moment and it should get disappeared. Please help in creating a temp table to view the data i extracted in the cursor.how can i get only people having A in their names without using condition where user_username like '%a%'.please help me in this ..

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost PROCEDURE PRO_ABC_DUMMY()
BEGIN
    declare v_user_id int;
    declare v_username varchar(100);
    declare dummy_cur cursor for
    SELECT user_id, user_fullname
    FROM m_users
    WHERE User_FullName LIKE '%a%';

    open dummy_cur;

    BLOCK1:BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END;
        LOOP1:LOOP
            fetch dummy_cur into v_user_id, v_username;
            insert into mm_users_dummy (user_id, user_name)
            values
            (v_user_id, v_username);
        END LOOP loop1;
    END BLOCK1;

    CLOSE dummy_cur;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: See doc.: [13.1.18 CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

BEGIN
    DECLARE v_user_id INT;
    DECLARE v_username VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE dummy_cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT user_id, user_fullname
    FROM m_users
    WHERE User_FullName LIKE '%a%';

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `mtest`(
```

`user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
);

```
OPEN dummy_cur;

BLOCK1:BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND BEGIN END;
    LOOP1:LOOP
        FETCH dummy_cur INTO v_user_id, v_username;
        INSERT INTO mtest (user_id, user_name)
        VALUES
        (v_user_id, v_username);
    END LOOP loop1;
END BLOCK1;

CLOSE dummy_cur;

SELECT * FROM mtest;
END$$
```